What is the equivalent powershell to this reg add with null value?
I'm trying to disable the annoying context menu in windows explorer using powershell.
The solution is supposedly using the following:
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" /f /ve

This works great, but I cannot get this to work using powershell's own registry functions. I've tried a variety of ways.
$LP2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $LP2 -Type String -Value "" -Force | Out-Null    
#  FAILS

Set-ItemProperty -Path $LP2 -Type String -Value ([byte[]]::new(0)) -Force | Out-Null  
#  FAILS

# And finally
$LP2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $LP2 -Name "InprocServer32" -Type String -Value ([byte[]]::new(0)) -Force | Out-Null

# Results in the permission error:
# Set-ItemProperty: Requested registry access is not allowed.


What's going on, and what is the equivalent to the reg add above?

UPDATE
I tried with the suggested solution from admin shell and now get some permission error.
$LP2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $LP2 -Name '(default)' -Type String -Value '' -Force | Out-Null

# Set-ItemProperty: Requested registry access is not allowed.



You can just run the reg add in powershell. What’s the reason for needing to change? Also, saying something fails doesn’t give much to go off. Are there errors? Please share those as well

You need to specify the value name: Set-ItemProperty ... -Name '(default)' -Value ''

@MathiasR.Jessen I get a permission error. (But not when using reg add.)

PS. What's going on with the SO markup? It can no longer markup powershell code correctly? (I use triple back-ticks + powershell.)

Have you checked the ACL for this particular reg key?

Re PowerShell syntax highlighting: there is currently no support for it, and trying to specify powershell falls back to guessing the language, which sometimes works reasonably well (if sh is guessed) and at other times results in fundamentally broken highlighting. The best stopgap for now is to use \``shor` explicitly. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421022/45375 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421016/45375

Administrative permissions aren't enough in this case, because the registry key in question is owned by TrustedInstaller, and only the latter has full access. You'd have to take ownership of the key, then grant yourself write access first.

@mklement0, permissions are one my weaker points.  If I understand correctly, he is saying REG.EXE is working, what exactly is REG.EXE doing behinds the scenes?  Is it taking ownership?

@Darin, the reg.exe command in the question isn't really working: it only appears to, because it targets HKCU (current user) rather than HKLM (local machine). The correct equivalent to the PowerShell attempt, reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" /f /ve, fails too (ERROR: Access is denied.)

@mklement0, thank you.  Sounds like this SO question is really about changing ownership of registry keys from within PowerShell.   This looks promising

Good point, @Darin, though it is also, originally about how to target the unnamed default value of a registry key in PowerShell. I've closed the question as a duplicate of two posts that address each of the problems (and I've used your link for the permissions issue). not2qubit: I'm hoping that the linked duplicates help you solve your problem. You can also use regedit.exe to take ownership of the key and assign yourself the required permissions interactively.

Thanks guys, I was quite tired when I did all this, and totally missed the fact that they were HKCU vs. HKLM. And with the take-ownership links, it all make sense now.

BTW. To check the ACL/ACE permissions, you can use:
Get-Acl -Path "$LP" | select * or for detailed permissions: Get-Acl -Path "$LP" | fl.

Instead of trying to set a registry value to $null or an empty string using Set-ItemProperty, why not use Clear-ItemProperty instead?
$LP2 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32'
Clear-ItemProperty -Path $LP2 -Name '(Default)'

Of course, since you are modifying a registry value in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE machine hive (HKLM:), you need admin permissions to do so.

Good point re Clear-ItemProperty. Either way, the non-obvious part is that a registry key's unnamed default value must be represented as verbatim '(Default)' in PowerShell. Administrative permissions aren't enough in this case, because the registry key in question is owned by TrustedInstaller, and only the latter has full access.

UPDATE:

The statement below (marked with strike-through), concerning the REG.EXE command not working, was incorrect.  I had a copy paste error when I tried to test the command.
This answer does not fix, bypass, or resolve the root issue of the question being asked.  To solve the root problem, it will likely require taking ownership of the desired registry key, which will require an answer similar to this.
I'm keeping this answer here since it is still a valid, but more complex, method for creating an empty default value in a registry key.

The Microsoft.Win32 way:
Registry is, without question, a "There's more than one way to skin a cat" type of thing.  Due to the increased complexity of this answer, I present this as a "If all else fails, do this" option.
The REG.EXE command in the question doesn't work as is, and appears to be missing the last few parameters.  I'll assume the missing part is /t REG_SZ /d "", and assume the following is the command we intend on mimicking:
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d ""
The following replicates the behavior of the above REG.EXE command:
using namespace Microsoft.Win32
try {
   $obk = [RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([RegistryHive]::CurrentUser, [RegistryView]::Registry64)
   $rwSubKey = $obk.CreateSubKey('Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32')
   if ($null -ne $rwSubKey) {
      $ValueName = ''
      $ValueData = ''
      $rwSubKey.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData, [RegistryValueKind]::String)
   }
}
catch {
   Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
}
finally {
   if ($null -ne $rwSubKey) {
      $rwSubKey.Dispose()
   }
}

NOTES:

The docs for CreateSubKey (string subkey) state:


Creates a new subkey or opens an existing subkey for write access.


CreateSubKey comes in 7 flavors, so if you continue to have problems, there may still be a solution.
In the experiments I did, using [RegistryView]::Registry32 reports no errors, but does NOT create the desired registry value in the desired location.  Instead, it creates it here:


SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32


Successfully tested in both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.4.2.


You can leave out /t REG_SZ as it default to the same, and as /ve add the empty value name as (default), so the data doesn't really matter. In fact it is still the same, before and after the "fix".

@not2qubit, sorry, I was wrong.  Corrected answer.

Try New-Item.
It resets the key if it already exists when bound with the Force switch parameter. So all the subsequent name-value pairs will be deleted.
New-Item -Path $LP2 -Force

